# Strikethrough a row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro that strikethrough a row only if it verifies a condition but it doesn't work. Can someomne tell me where is the problem.

My code is:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan Traitement Risque")
    For i = 6 To lr1 Step 1
      If Application.CountIf(col_2, .Range("B" & i).Value) = 0 Then
        .Rows(i).Font.Strikethrough
      End If
    Next i 
End with
```

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Jeeped's comment is a far more efficient solution - but if you want to go the VBA route then you need to use:

```
.Rows(i).Font.Strikethrough = True
```

`Strikethrough` is a property, not a method, and so in this case you need to explicitly set the value to `True` or `False`